# Add classes to parent nodes (<a>) in a nested list

Tags: javascript, html, css

The `<a>` inside the last `<li>` of the innermost `<ul>` has a class which is named `current`. It highlights the active link.

I want to highlight all links that are parents from this link.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="a.html">Samsung</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="b.html">Galaxy</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="c.html">Galaxy Note 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="c.html" class="current">Galaxy S 5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*Galaxy S 5* has the class `current`, but I also want to add the class `current` to the parent links (*Samsung*, *Galaxy*).

Comment: Where is the code that adds the `current` class to Galaxy S 5?

Comment: @neilsimp1 I changed the code have a look again,                     <a href="c.html" Class='current'>Galaxy S 5</a>

Comment: Can you show the javascript you're currently working on?

Comment: I mean where is the code that adds the class to the `<a>` tag? I had assumed there was some javascript that would do this, and your solution could probably be added into that. Or does this `class="current"` come this way from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Define an outermost parent element by giving it an id.
2. Get the element with the current class and assign it to a temp var.
3. Loop over the elements starting with your current element and change the value of the temp var to `temp.parentNode`. If the elements parent node is a list item add your current class to the first child element of the list element.

```js
var until = document.getElementById("list"),
    crnt = document.getElementsByClassName('current'),
    tmp = crnt.item(0);

while(tmp !== until) {
  if(tmp.tagName === "LI") {
    tmp.children.item(0).classList.add("current");
  }
  tmp = tmp.parentNode;
}
```

```css
.current {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <a href="a.html">Samsung</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="b.html">Galaxy</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="c.html">Galaxy Note 4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="c.html" class="current">Galaxy S 5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: thank @DavidDomain it worked perfectly and dynamically amazing code

Comment: Sure, happy coding. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('current')

for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if(els[i].parentNode != null)
        els[i].parentNode.className += ' current'; 
}
```

Comment: I suppose the OP actually wants the class on the anchor tags, not the list and item tags.

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="a.html">Samsung</a>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="b.html">Galaxy</a>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <a href="c.html">Galaxy Note 4</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="c.html" id="s5">Galaxy S 5</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li> 
</ul>
```

JavaScript :

```
<script>
   ele = document.getElementById("s5");
   par1 = ele.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode; 
   par1.children[0].className+="current";
   par2 = par1.parentNode.parentNode;
   par2.children[0].className+="current";
</script>
```

I've used parentNode to select parent element.starting from the last children.Hope this will work for you. :)

Comment: Thanks @Aruna Warnasooriya It wokrs fine

Comment: but one thing its not dynamic ,u have to add procedure for all parents
but in any way thanks again its working

Answer (score 0):

There are six *parents* from the inside `class="current"`. Suppose there are no other classes that are named with `current`.

Take the **inside** **node** and go from there to the **outside** **node**. Add the **parentNode** to the current node.

```
node = node.parentNode
```

As been said there are six nodes from there.

```
var count = 0;
var max = 6;
while(count < max) { ...; count += 1 }
```

Check if the node name is a `<li>` and **not** the inside `<li>`. Add to the first child, which is the `<a>` the class name.

```
if(node.nodeName === "LI") {
    if(count > 1) {
        node.children[0].className = "myClass";
    }
}
```

```js
// If there are no other classes that are named with "current"
// There are six parents from inside node

var node = document.getElementsByClassName("current")[0];
var count = 0;
var max = 6; 
var cN = "current";

while (count < max) { // 6 times (ul li ul li ul li)
    node = node.parentNode;
    if (node.nodeName === "LI") {
        if (count > 1) { // Not <li> inside
            node.children[0].className = cN; // <a>
        }
    }
    count += 1;
}
```

```css
.current {
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="a.html">Samsung</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="b.html">Galaxy</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="c.html">Galaxy Note 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="c.html" class='current'>Galaxy S 5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```